# map each word in string to reorder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I am trying to re-order my strings slightly. I believe I need to do this my using `.map` so, I need to re-order the strings Set N Total Games Over/Under N. N representing a random number. This is stored in the var of `market`. This would need reordering to Under/Over N Total Games Set N. I have started to do this by using a lot of messy if statements, and using `substr` but this is not a great solution as my code looks really messy, and is not a great solution anyway. I wondered if there was any better way of doing this.

As for the string , each marketLabel will be slightly different only that the number (N) could be different each time, but the maximum number N can be is 5 if this helps.

At the minute code wise this is what I have:

```
if (marketLabel.includes('Set' && 'Total Games Over/Under')) {
  var splits = 'foo'; // = marketLabel.split('/');
  var set = 'foo';
  var market = 'foo';
  if(marketLabel.includes('Set 1')) {
    var arr = marketLabel.split(" ").map(function (val) {
      console.log(String(val));
      return String(val) + 1;
    });
  }
  if(marketLabel.includes('Set 2')) {
    splits = marketLabel.split('Set 2');
    set = marketLabel.substr(0, marketLabel.indexOf('2')+1);
    return "Under/Over" + splits + " " + set;
  }
  if(marketLabel.includes('Set 3')) {
    splits = marketLabel.split('Set 3');
    set = "set 3";
    console.log('foo 3');
  }
  if(marketLabel.includes('Set 4')) {
    set = "set 4"
    splits = marketLabel.split('Set 4');
    console.log('foo 4');
  }
  if(marketLabel.includes('Set 5')) {
    set = "set 5"
    splits = marketLabel.split('Set 1');
    console.log('foo 5');
  }
```

So in summary, what I need is the marketLabel which could be one of the following:

```
Set 1 Total Games Over/Under 9.5
Set 2 Total Games Over/Under 9.5
Set 3 Total Games Over/Under 9.5
Set 4 Total Games Over/Under 9.5
Set 5 Total Games Over/Under 9.5
```

to be re-ordered into:

```
Under/Over 9.5 Total Games Set 1
Under/Over 9.5 Total Games Set 2
Under/Over 9.5 Total Games Set 3
Under/Over 9.5 Total Games Set 4
Under/Over 9.5 Total Games Set 5
```

Comment: You should post your code - I can't really make sense of what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uging regular expressions:

```js
market = "Set 1 Total Games Over/Under 9.5";
regex = /Set ([0-9.]+) Total Games (Over)\/(Under) ([0-9.]+)/
var match = regex.exec(market);
var newStr = match[3] + '/' + match[2] + ' ' + match[1] + ' Total Games Set ' + match[4];
console.log(newStr);
```

Numbers, `Over` and `Under` strings are captured and reordered by printing the `match` array elements.

A schema is better than words:

[image]

You can also just capture numbers and inject them in string in correct order:

```js
market = "Set 1 Total Games Over/Under 9.5";
regex = /Set ([0-9.]+) Total Games Over\/Under ([0-9.]+)/
var match = regex.exec(market);
var newStr = 'Under/Over ' + match[1] + ' Total Games Set ' + match[2];
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: So, now I have this rendering correctly to the browser using `return['Under/Over %s Total Games Set %s',match[2], match[1]]` however the actual `%s` is rendered in the browser.

Comment: I edited to add a `newStr` variable set with the concatenation of strings and array elements.